# Cast to Base* from void* being any Derived<I>*

Tags: c++, casting, polymorphism, virtual-inheritance

In a scenario where I use an external library allowing me to store some user data through a `void*`, I am faced with a situation where I must store a pointer to different `Derived<I>` instancing virtually inheriting from a common `Base` type (in all actuality, to different derived types instead of a single templated one; but that simplifies the question).

Although a similar question ["Conversion from void* to the pointer of the base class"](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5445105/conversion-from-void-to-the-pointer-of-the-base-class) and [its duplicate](//stackoverflow.com/questions/42791013/how-to-cast-from-void-to-virtual-base-class-without-exact-type-info) exists, the answers assume what the exact pointed-to type is known, and while some of my code using that opaque pointer knows what actual (polymorphic) type is the object being pointed to, some don't (it might even not be my code); but the predicate that the pointed-to type virtually inherits from Base is always true in this case. Up-casting the pointer before storing it is **not** an option either since in my use case for a given object instance, multiple `Derived<I>` may exist in its hierarchy, making it impossible to down-cast to the right `Derived<I>`.

I have tested through the following code (on Linux x86_64, GCC 7.1.1) the ability to get the type info back from an opaque pointer using RTTI:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cxxabi.h>
struct Base {
  Base() { printf("Base is at %p\n", this); }
  virtual ~Base() {}
};
template<int I>
struct Derived : public virtual Base {
  Derived() { printf("Derived<%i> is at %p\n", I, this); }
  virtual ~Derived() {}
};
const char* demangle(const char *mangled) {
  return abi::__cxa_demangle(mangled, 0, 0, nullptr);
}
int main(int, char**) {
  Derived<1> d1;
  Derived<2> d2;
  void *unkPtr1 = &d1, *unkPtr2 = &d2;
  printf("unkPtr1 -> %s\n", demangle(typeid(*reinterpret_cast<Base*>(unkPtr1)).name()));
  printf("unkPtr2 -> %s\n", demangle(typeid(*reinterpret_cast<Base*>(unkPtr2)).name()));
  return 0;
}
```

I am unsure if `reinterpret_cast`ing in this case is any kind of safe, but it Works For Me™ on `typeid` expressions.

A possible output is

```
Base is at 0x7ffff9ee4478
Derived<1> is at 0x7ffff9ee4478
Base is at 0x7ffff9ee4480
Derived<2> is at 0x7ffff9ee4480
unkPtr1 -> Derived<1>
unkPtr2 -> Derived<2>
```

This shows there is sufficient type information to know where we are in the inheritance hierarchy for any pointer to a virtually `Base`-derived type.

Trying to `dynamic_cast<Base*>(reinterpret_cast<Base*>(unkPtr1))` is obviously invalid and unsafe (`unkPtr1` is actually a `Derived<1>*`), and a no-op.

Is it possible to use the facilities provided by `dynamic_cast`s or RTTI in a *relatively* type-safe way to get a pointer to `Base` back from `Derived<I>`-pointing `void*`s?

Comment: There is no magic you can do with a `void*`.   Both sender and receiver have to know what is being sent / received to properly cast to the correct type.  All of that what you're doing now is fool's gold.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm You can **not** pass a `void` to `dynamic_cast` since `void*` is not a polymorphic type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This shows there is sufficient type information to know where we are in the inheritance hierarchy for any pointer to a virtually Base-derived type.

It most certainly does not. It proves only that "undefined behavior" for your compiler happened to mean "do what you expected." It proves that the implementation you're using gives the virtual base class the same address as the derived class. In this particular case.

As far as the C++ standard is concerned, the *only thing* you can cast a `void*` back to is the original type it was when the conversion to `void*` was made (or to byte-wise pointers like `unsigned char*`). It doesn't matter if you use `reinterpret_cast`, C-style casts, or whatever. If the original pointer was a some type, you cannot cast it to the base class.

Well, you can cast it there. But you can't do anything with the pointer except cast it back to `void*`.

> Up-casting the pointer before storing it is not an option either since in my use case for a given object instance, multiple `Derived<I>` may exist in its hierarchy, making it impossible to down-cast to the right `Derived<I>`.

Nonsense. The sending code must know what the type is, since it's casting it to a `void*`. And since it knows what the type is, it must also know what the base type is. So the ways in which this could be a problem are:

1. if you have multiple base types, and the sending code has no idea which base type the receiving code is using.
2. if the sending code is a template and doesn't know anything about the type other than the fact that it needs to be sent, yet the receiving code expects a specific base class.

All of these cases effectively mean you have written *incoherent* code. One of the two parties, sender or receiver, is ignorant of the type that the other party expects. If the sender and receiver can't agree on a type for transmittance, then there is *no way* for the sender to send it in a way that the receiver can understand it.

Make your code coherent, and the problem goes away.

Comment: I've found a way that solves the type knowledge problem you describe: having `Derived<I>` non-virtually inherit from an `Intermediate` class itself virtually inheriting from `Base`, and storing the `Intermediate*` into the `void*`. This is sufficient for what I want to achieve (being able to go both down to the only `Derived<I>` underneath and up to the base), and brings back type coherence.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that doesn't work.  Using `void *` is the programmer's way of telling the compiler they know what the underlying type is, and the `reinterpret_cast` is how the programmer *tells* the compiler what the type is.  The only reason you haven't immediately noticed the error in your example is because the classes have no data, thus the base pointer is the same as the derived pointer.  As soon as data comes along, things don't line up so well.  For instance, modifying your example:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <string>

struct Base {
    explicit Base(const int inInt) :
      test1(inInt)
    { printf("Base is at %p\n", this); }
    virtual ~Base() {}

    int test1;
};

template<int I>
struct Derived : public virtual Base {
    Derived(const int inInt) :
      Base(inInt),
      testStr("Derived string")
    { printf("Derived<%i> is at %p\n", I, this); }
    virtual ~Derived() {}

    std::string testStr;
};

const char* demangle(const char *mangled) {
  return abi::__cxa_demangle(mangled, 0, 0, nullptr);
}

int main(int, char**) {
  Derived<1> d1(1);
  Derived<2> d2(2);
  void *unkPtr1 = &d1, *unkPtr2 = &d2;
  Base *basePtr1 = reinterpret_cast<Base*>(unkPtr1);
  Base *basePtr2 = reinterpret_cast<Base*>(unkPtr2);
  Base *realBase1 = &d1;
  Base *realBase2 = &d2;
  printf("basePtr1 %p, realBase1 %p -> %s\n", basePtr1, realBase1, demangle(typeid(*basePtr1).name()));
  printf("basePtr2 %p, realBase2 %p -> %s\n", basePtr2, realBase2, demangle(typeid(*basePtr2).name()));

  printf("realBase1 %d\n", realBase1->test1);
  printf("realBase2 %d\n", realBase2->test1);

  // This may crash, or give bogus values, depending on the exact compiler output.
  printf("basePtr1 %d\n", basePtr1->test1);
  printf("basePtr2 %d\n", basePtr2->test1);

  return 0;
}
```

Using the above code I get:

```
Base is at 0x7ffce4892ae8
Derived<1> is at 0x7ffce4892ac0
Base is at 0x7ffce4892aa8
Derived<2> is at 0x7ffce4892a80
basePtr1 0x7ffce4892ac0, realBase1 0x7ffce4892ae8 -> Derived<1>
basePtr2 0x7ffce4892a80, realBase2 0x7ffce4892aa8 -> Derived<2>
realBase1 1
realBase2 2
basePtr1 -460772648
basePtr2 -460772712
```

So using the normal pointer-to-base, you get the correct dereferenced value, however hopping through `void`, you get bogus values.

I believe your only option is to ensure the pointer that is stored into the `void *` is of the `Base` type.  That way you code which runs later, knows what you have.  You might also have some luck going through some form of variant implementation, such as `QVariant` or `boost::any`.  Then using a `void *` pointer to the variant type.  However, you state that casting to `Base *` first isn't really an option, so I assume changing the type going in won't be an option anyway.

As best as I can tell you can't accomplish what you want reliably.  You'll have to compromise somewhere, probably requiring the `void *` be from `Base *`.

Comment: Why are some function parameters const?

Comment: They are const to indicate to the compiler that they shouldn't be changed. This is obviously useful for pass by reference parameters, since it also indicates to the caller that the referenced value won't be changed, but is even useful for pass by value, since modification of the passed in value almost certainly indicates a logic error. This way the compiler can flag it for you. I always assume const by default, and only after consideration, allow it to be mutable.

Comment: Too true! Even though in this case it was just copy-paste from the op's example, I'll admit to *rarely* using `const char * const`. Not terribly consistent I realize.

Comment: I thought this was guaranteed, but it's only if both derived and base are stardard-layout types -- so no virtual inheritance (used here), no virtual functions (also used...) and a couple other constraints. Perhaps this could be added to the answer.